# Best way to run two docker compose apps behind nginx on one host machine?

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I have two docker-compose apps:

- a.com
- b.com

I want to run them both on the same host machine and put an nginx container proxy to route incoming requests to the correct services within each of the docker-compose apps.

I think I need to have a single nginx container running separately from the two docker-compose apps. I previously used [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy), but my routing has got more complex, so I want to run my own nginx instance now.

- I can't work out how to network the two apps and the nginx container to make this all work in a sane way.
- When I `docker run` the nginx container I'm getting: `host not found in upstream "MY_CONTAINER_HOST_NAME"`, which suggests my app hostname isn't resolving from within the nginx container.
- I can post my nginx config if need be, but this is really a docker networking/ best-practice question.

Answer (score 1):

nginx-proxy should be good enough, provided it supports a docker swarm attached network ([issue 520](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/520), still pending)

You could also consider [`vfarcic/docker-flow-proxy`](https://github.com/vfarcic/docker-flow-proxy), an easy way to reconfigure proxy every time a new service is deployed, or when a service is scaled.

See "[Integrating Proxy With Docker Swarm (Tour Around Docker 1.12 Series)](https://technologyconversations.com/2016/08/01/integrating-proxy-with-docker-swarm-tour-around-docker-1-12-series/)" for a concrete example.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm really looking to learn how to do this by hand to understand how Docker works. What's the best way to write my own nginx proxy to manage two compose apps on one host machine?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 options for this:

**First:**

Run both apps and nginx in the same docker user-defined network. In order to do this you need to create a user-defined network first:

```
docker network create appnet
```

Then change your docker-files to use the appnet network as external (external networks wont create network and use existing)

**Second:**

Create 2 user-defined networks, named appnet1 and appnet2, attach a.com to appnet1 and b.com to appnet2 marked as external network in docker-compose. Then bring up the nginx and attach it to both appnet1 and appnet2.

> When I docker run the nginx container I'm getting: host not found in
>   upstream "MY_CONTAINER_HOST_NAME", which suggests my app hostname
>   isn't resolving from within the nginx container.

Please note: User defined networks will provide internal DNS so you can call containers on the same network by container name.

**External network example:**

If you want your containers to join a pre-existing network, use the external option:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my-pre-existing-network
```

Instead of attempting to create a network called [projectname]_default, Compose will look for a network called my-pre-existing-network and connect your app’s containers to it